# Magento 2: Display category list and end child category only show product list

Tags: magento-2.1, product, category-products

**Display category list and end child category only show product list**

- My custom theme

> Magento_Catalog/category/products.phtml

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>
<?php
/**
 * Category view template
 *
 * @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View
 */
?>
<?php
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$category = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_category');
$subcats = $category->getChildrenCategories();
//var_dump($category->getData());
//var_dump($category->getIsAnchor());
//var_dump($subcats->count());
if ($subcats && ($category->getIsAnchor() != '1' || $category->getIsAnchor() != 1)) { ?>
    <ul class="sub-category-list">
        <?php
        foreach ($subcats as $subcat) {
            if ($subcat->getIsActive()) {
                $_category = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($subcat->getId());
                $subcaturl = $subcat->getUrl();
                $_imgHtml = '';
                if ($_imgUrl = $_category->getImageUrl()) {
                    $_imgHtml = '<img src="' . $_imgUrl . '" />';
                } else {
                    $mediaUrl = $objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface')->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);
                    $_imgHtml = '<img src="' . $mediaUrl. 'catalog/category/default.jpg" />';
                }
                ?>
                <li class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 text-center sub-category">
                    <a href="<?php echo $subcaturl; ?>" class="block-promo" title="<?php echo $subcat->getName(); ?>">
                        <?php echo $_imgHtml; ?>
                        <span style="background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.9)" class="content bg-white">
                        <strong><?php echo $subcat->getName(); ?></strong>
                    </span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            <?php }
        } ?>
    </ul>
<?php } else { ?>
<?php if (!$block->isContentMode() || $block->isMixedMode()): ?>
    <?php echo $block->getProductListHtml() ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php } ?>
```

`Not display category list` `only show product list`

Remove `else` part show `category list only not product list`

what mistake i am done i don't know

Answer (score 0):

In magento,product listing is shown when both for *Non-anchor and Anchor categories*.

And as per ,you code you have remove product listing  when it is not anchor category that means **your conditions is wrong.It should  like:**

```
<?php if($subcats && ($category->getIsAnchor() != '1' || $category->getIsAnchor() != 1)) { ?>
<ul class="sub-category-list">
        <?php
        foreach ($subcats as $subcat) {
            if ($subcat->getIsActive()) {
                $_category = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($subcat->getId());
                $subcaturl = $subcat->getUrl();
                $_imgHtml = '';
                if ($_imgUrl = $_category->getImageUrl()) {
                    $_imgHtml = '<img src="' . $_imgUrl . '" />';
                } else {
                    $mediaUrl = $objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface')->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);
                    $_imgHtml = '<img src="' . $mediaUrl. 'catalog/category/default.jpg" />';
                }
                ?>
                <li class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 text-center sub-category">
                    <a href="<?php echo $subcaturl; ?>" class="block-promo" title="<?php echo $subcat->getName(); ?>">
                        <?php echo $_imgHtml; ?>
                        <span style="background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.9)" class="content bg-white">
                        <strong><?php echo $subcat->getName(); ?></strong>
                    </span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            <?php }
        } ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif ?>

<?php if (!$block->isContentMode() || $block->isMixedMode()): ?>
    <?php echo $block->getProductListHtml() ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Hai Amit Bera,  May i know  correct way of condition

Comment: Already  add the condition  on answer